# Reading from text file into python list

Tags: python, arrays, list, loops, file-io

Very new to python and can't understand why this isn't working. I have a list of web addresses stored line by line in a text file. I want to store the first 10 in an array/list called bing, the next 10 in a list called yahoo, and the last 10 in a list called duckgo. I'm using the `readlines` function to read the data from the file into each array. The problem is nothing is being written to the lists. The count is incrementing like it should. Also, if I remove the loops altogether and just read the whole text file into one list it works perfectly. This leads me to believe that the loops are causing the problem. The code I am using is below. Would really appreciate some feedback.

```
count=0;

#Open the file
fo=open("results.txt","r")

#read into each array
while(count<30):
    if(count<10):
        bing = fo.readlines()
        count+=1
        print bing
        print count

    elif(count>=10 and count<=19):
        yahoo = fo.readlines()
        count+=1
        print count

    elif(count>=20 and count<=29):
        duckgo = fo.readlines()
        count+=1
        print count

print bing
print yahoo
print duckgo

fo.close
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You're using `readlines` to read the files. `readlines` reads *all* of the lines at once, so the very first time through your loop, you exhaust the entire file and store the result in `bing`. Then, every time through the loop, you overwrite `bing`, `yahoo`, or `duckgo` with the (empty) result of the next `readlines` call. So your lists all wind up being empty.

There are lots of ways to fix this. Among other things, you should consider reading the file a line at a time, with `readline` (no 's'). Or better yet, you could iterate over the file, line by line, simply by using a `for` loop:

```
for line in fo:
    ...
```

To keep the structure of your current code you could use `enumerate`:

```
for line_number, line in enumerate(fo):
    if condition(line_number):
        ...
```

But frankly I think you should ditch your current system. A much simpler way would be to use `readlines` without a loop, and slice the resulting list!

```
lines = fo.readlines()
bing = lines[0:10]
yahoo = lines[10:20]
duckgo = lines[20:30]
```

There are many other ways to do this, and some might be better, but none are simpler!

Comment: Python never ceases to amaze me with its simplicity. This is exactly what I was looking for thank you for the clear and informative answer

Comment: Wow, this answer is almost word for word the same as what I started writing. Stop reading my mind, senderle! I guess this is a consequence of there being one right way to do it. :)

Comment: This isn't a big deal, but `file` is a keyword in Python 2.x and I don't like to use keywords as variable names.  Also I like terse names.  So I usually use `f` instead of `file` as the variable for an open file-handle object.

Comment: @steveha, yeah I use `f` too -- I was coding stream-of-consciousness style and forgot to edit my metasyntactic variables. Thanks! I'll go for `fo`, for consistency here.

Answer (score 1):

`readlines()` reads all of the lines of the file.  If you call it again, you get empty list.  So you are overwriting your lists with empty data when you iterate through your loop.

Answer (score 1):

You should be using `readline()` instead of `readlines()`

`readlines()` reads the entire file in at once, whereas `readline()` reads a single line from the file.

Answer (score 1):

I suggest you rewrite it like so:

```
bing = []
yahoo = []
duckgo = []
with open("results.txt", "r") as f:
    for i, line in enumerate(f):
        if i < 10:
            bing.append(line)
        elif i < 20:
            yahoo.append(line)
        elif i < 30:
            duckgo.append(line)
        else:
            raise RuntimeError, "too many lines in input file"
```

Note how we use `enumerate()` to get a running count of lines, rather than making our own `count` variable and needing to increment it ourselves.  This is considered good style in Python.

But I think the best way to solve this problem would be to use `itertools` like so:

```
import itertools as it
with open("results.txt", "r") as f:
    bing = list(it.islice(f, 10))
    yahoo = list(it.islice(f, 10)) 
    duckgo = list(it.islice(f, 10))
    if list(it.islice(f, 1)):
        raise RuntimeError, "too many lines in input file"
```

`itertools.islice()` (or `it.islice()` since I did the `import itertools as it`) will pull a specified number of items from an iterator.  Our open file-handle object `f` is an iterator that returns lines from the file, so `it.islice(f, 10)` pulls exactly 10 lines from the input file.

Because `it.islice()` returns an iterator, we must explicitly expand it out to a `list` by wrapping it in `list()`.

I think this is the simplest way to do it.  It perfectly expresses what we want: for each one, we want a list with 10 lines from the file.  There is no need to keep a counter at all, just pull the 10 lines each time!

EDIT: The check for extra lines now uses `it.islice(f, 1)` so that it will only pull a single line.  Even one extra line is enough to know that there are more than just the 30 expected lines, and this way if someone accidentally runs this code on a very large file, it won't try to slurp the whole file into memory.